How should I deal with multiple imports having the same name
I have a repository that contains multiple programs:
.
└── Programs
    ├── program1
    │   └── Generic_named.py
    └── program2
        └── Generic_named.py

I would like to add testing to this repository.
I have attempted to do it like this:
.
├── Programs
│   ├── program1
│   │   └── Generic_named.py
│   └── program2
│       └── Generic_named.py
└── Tests
    ├── mock
    │   ├── 1
    │   │   └── custom_module.py
    │   └── 2
    │       └── custom_module.py
    ├── temp
    ├── test1.py
    └── test2.py

Where temp is a folder to store each program temporarily with mock versions of any required imports that can not be stored directly with the program.
Suppose we use a hello world example like this:
cat Programs/program1/Generic_named.py
import custom_module

def main():
    return custom_module.out()


cat Programs/program2/Generic_named.py
import custom_module

def main():
    return custom_module.out("Goodbye, World!")


cat Tests/mock/1/custom_module.py
def out():return "Hello, World!"


cat Tests/mock/2/custom_module.py
def out(x):return x

And I were to use these scripts to test it:
cat Tests/test1.py
import unittest
import os
import sys
import shutil

if os.path.exists('Tests/temp/1'):
    shutil.rmtree('Tests/temp/1')

shutil.copytree('Tests/mock/1', 'Tests/temp/1/')
shutil.copyfile('Programs/program1/Generic_named.py', 'Tests/temp/1/Generic_named.py')

sys.path.append('Tests/temp/1')
import Generic_named
sys.path.remove('Tests/temp/1')

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case1(self):
            self.assertEqual(Generic_named.main(), "Hello, World!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()



cat Tests/test2.py
import unittest
import os
import sys
import shutil

if os.path.exists('Tests/temp/2'):
    shutil.rmtree('Tests/temp/2')

shutil.copytree('Tests/mock/2', 'Tests/temp/2')
shutil.copyfile('Programs/program2/Generic_named.py', 'Tests/temp/2/Generic_named.py')

sys.path.append('Tests/temp/2')
import Generic_named
sys.path.remove('Tests/temp/2')

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case1(self):
            self.assertEqual(Generic_named.main(), "Goodbye, World!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Both tests pass when run individually:
python3 -m unittest Tests/test1.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK


python3 -m unittest Tests/test2.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK

However, they fail when being run together:
python3 -m unittest discover -p test*.py -s Tests/
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_case1 (test2.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/s/Documents/Coding practice/2024/Test Mess/1/Tests/test2.py", line 18, in test_case1
    self.assertEqual(Generic_named.main(), "Goodbye, World!")
AssertionError: 'Hello, World!' != 'Goodbye, World!'
- Hello, World!
+ Goodbye, World!


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)

If I try to use a different temporary name for one of the scripts I am trying to test,
cat Tests/test2.py
import unittest
import os
import sys
import shutil

if os.path.exists('Tests/temp/2'):
    shutil.rmtree('Tests/temp/2')

shutil.copytree('Tests/mock/2', 'Tests/temp/2')
shutil.copyfile('Programs/program2/Generic_named.py', 'Tests/temp/2/Generic_named1.py')

sys.path.append('Tests/temp/2')
import Generic_named1
sys.path.remove('Tests/temp/2')

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case1(self):
            self.assertEqual(Generic_named1.main(), "Goodbye, World!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Then I get a different error:
python3 -m unittest discover -p test*.py -s Tests/
.E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_case1 (test2.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/s/Documents/Coding practice/2024/Test Mess/2/Tests/test2.py", line 18, in test_case1
    self.assertEqual(Generic_named1.main(), "Goodbye, World!")
  File "/home/s/Documents/Coding practice/2024/Test Mess/2/Tests/temp/2/Generic_named1.py", line 4, in main
    return custom_module.out("Goodbye, World!")
TypeError: out() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)

It seems to be trying to import the same file, despite me using a different file from a different path with the same name. This seems strange, as I've been making sure to undo any changes to the Python Path after importing what I wish to test. Is there any way to mock the path? I can't change the name of the custom_module, as that would require changing the programs I wish to test.
How should I write, approach, or setup these tests such that they can be tested with unittest discover the same as they can individually?

Why do you have multiple scripts with the same name? Modules can share a name, because their containing package disambiguates them. Scripts don't belong to any package, so should have unique names within the scope of your project.

Why do you copy around files? Just import first.Generic_Named as gn1 and similarly for gn2 to keep them separate.

@tripleee I have tested your solution but it does not work..Please write an answer with  all the code you suggest.

this really looks much ado about nothing. The import ... from ... as ...  syntas as @triplee mentions should provide everything you need there.

@tripleee “Why do you copy around files?” Because the Programs folder does not contain the scripts that the programs need to import in order to be able to run.

I have reproduced all your tests on my system and I have obtained exactly your output with the execution of the tests individually (SUCCESS) and together (FAIL).
I have also changed the name of Generic_named.py --> Generic_named1.py, as you have done, and I have obtained exactly your second error message:
TypeError: out() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

So the only solution I have found is to rename also mock/2/custom_module.py. However, this also eliminates name collisions (which is your real problem)! However your question contains absolutely reproducible code and is useful to look at.

In the rest of the answer there are the details.
The content of dictionary sys.modules explains the reason of failure
In this paragraph I have tried to explain the reason because with discover option happens the problem.
If you add the instruction:
print(sys.modules['Generic_named'])

in your test methods you obtained the following code in the files test1.py and test2.py:
cat cat Tests/test1.py
...
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case1(self):
        print(sys.modules['Generic_named'])   # <---------NOTE THIS INSTRUCTION
        self.assertEqual(Generic_named.main(), "Hello, World!")
...

cat Tests/test2.py
...
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case1(self):
        print(sys.modules['Generic_named'])   # <---------NOTE THIS INSTRUCTION
        self.assertEqual(Generic_named.main(), "Goodbye, World!")
...

By the individually execution of test1.py and test2.py you obtain:
python -m unittest Tests/test1.py
<module 'Generic_named' from 'Tests/temp/1/Generic_named.py'>
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK


python -m unittest Tests/test2.py
<module 'Generic_named' from 'Tests/temp/2/Generic_named.py'>
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK


The previous output shows that the name Generic_named points to different scripts in the first and in the second execution.
Instead, if you execute tests together, the output of the introduced print instruction is:
# for test1
<module 'Generic_named' from 'Tests/temp/1/Generic_named.py'>

# THE SAME for test2
<module 'Generic_named' from 'Tests/temp/1/Generic_named.py'>

This shows that with the execution by the discover option is imported always the same script Tests/temp/1/Generic_named.py, so the test in the file test2.py fails.
Rename also mock/2/custom_module.py
After the change of the name of program2/Generic_named.py --->  program2/Generic_named1.py, I suggest you to renamed also (if you can) the name of the module mock/2/custom_module.py to mock/2/custom_module1.py.
Modify import inside of Generic_name1.py
After that you have to modify also the import inside program2/Generic_name1.py so that this file becomes:
cat Programs/program2/Generic_named1.py
#import custom_module # <--- your instruction
import custom_module1

def main():
    #return custom_module.out("Goodbye, World!") # <--- your instruction
    return custom_module1.out("Goodbye, World!")

Eventually the correct output with discover option
In this way the execution of the tests by the command python3 -m unittest discover -p test*.py -s Tests/ has success as you can see in its output below:
python -m unittest discover -p test*.py -s Tests/
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK


